# Regression (and Forecasting) on Rent

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, regression, forecast

The data table below contains cash flows going into an account. At index 0 the account starts with 50 in debt, is charged a monthly Rent of 90, and pays a certain amount every month, as well as getting additional supporting payments every 4 periods.

[image: Initial Data]

Assuming we know the first 8 periods (in order to form an opinion on the account, and to notice the seasonality of "Support"), how do we define the true balance based on previous and potentially future figures? The goal is to state how much someone actually has to pay, based on their current (and future forecasted) payment patterns.

For example, as below, if a "Support" transaction is missed in a week where it was expected, the true balance spikes up, but then if that payment was received, the true balance goes back down.

[image: Missed Support]

So far I've managed to confirm the following:

- Rent is a known array (for past and future)
- Payment is historically known and can be forecasted using ARIMA
- Support is historically known and can be forecasted using Exponential Smoothing

I've tried to find a way to create a regression equation based on historical and forecasted values (so that the true balance takes into accounts expected payments), but so far I've not managed to do so. It feels like I'm hitting a brick wall and I would appreciate information if the way I'm attempting to do so is correct or not.

Note: The information provided here contains very simplified data. In reality, "Payment" can be highly irregular, while "Support" can either be a seasonal transaction that can be delayed by a number of periods, or can periodically stop and start again. I have so far been prototyping in Excel, as I'm unsure what to use to find a solution in Python.

Comment: You said "The goal is to state how much actually has to pay, based on their current payment patterns."

Do you mean the ACTUAL balance of the account now, or more like a prediction of how much they have to pay?

Comment: @CalZ A prediction of how much they have to pay. The actual balance is the opening balance at every period, and is easy to recursively calculate at time t as: opening balance + rent + payment + support (all at t-1).

I'm interested in how much someone should pay now to clear their account based on expected payment patterns over the next few weeks.

Comment: To further clarify: imagine an individual takes over a friend's tenancy, already owing 50 (this is his initial opening balance at t=0). He pays half his rent every week (45), knowing that his mother will always pay the other 4 halves every 4 weeks (180). That means that, at any one time, all he really owes is 50, the starting balance on that account, as all the other payments come in regularly. One week, his mother's payment does not come on time. The next opening balance should reflect that situation. However, if his mum remembers and pays the following week, it goes back to 50.

Comment: What is your real goal? Are you trying to forecast who will miss a payment? I understand the situation with someone else paying but that seems very dependent on the context. If each account has 1-n people paying at different frequencies, it would be hard to generate a generalizable forecast.

Comment: No, I am trying to create an adaptive balance that notifies you as soon as a forecasted payment did not occur. Basically if I say someone doesn't owe me anything purely because I know he will make a payment in x periods, and then x periods go by and that payment didn't come, then automatically his true balance gets updated to what I've "overlooked" because I was expecting a payment plus whatever else he owed. However, if the situation remedies itself within y periods, it will go back to the initial state

Comment: Ah. That sounds like an anomaly detection problem, except in this case the absence of an event is the anomaly you are trying to detect.

Comment: But I'm not only trying to detect when the payment is missing, I'm also interested in adapting a continuous value (the true balance) based on what happens now, in the past, and in the future, iteratively. Anomaly detection would only provide me with information when a payment was missed. Am I wrong and did you have something else in mind? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to give more context. As I wrote in previous comments, some of your examples with the mother paying and not paying are hard to generalize.

Comment: The most general case is: Rent is has the same value over n periods, Payment is anything from a steady stream to a random walk, and Support is a "theoretically seasonal" stream, but not necessarily, and can randomly be delayed or stop. I'm not sure how better than this to describe it. Just imagine you're not on a steady income and you give your landlord as much money as you can (sometimes being enough to cover rent, sometimes not), and from time to time random people come and help you with your rent. Assuming your recent pattern in both payments continue, how much are you estimated to owe.